# SQL Update stock When adding new invoice

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

When I update my current stock using following trigger work as expected. But when I update same value twice updated value is wrong.

50 - 2 = 48 but its shows 50 - 2 = 47

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trig_invoice_update] 
ON [dbo].[tblInvoice]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE p
    SET quantity = COALESCE(d.quantity, 0) - COALESCE(i.quantity, 0) 
    FROM tblPurchase p 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT i.itemName, SUM(i.quantity) AS quantity
         FROM tblInvoice i
         GROUP BY i.itemName) i ON p.itemName = i.itemName 
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT d.itemName, SUM(d.quantity) AS quantity
         FROM tblPurchase d
         GROUP BY d.itemName) d ON p.itemName = d.itemName
    WHERE d.quantity > 1
       OR i.quantity > 1;
END
```

Comment: Would you please share the table structures for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: Somehow, you should involve the `Inserted` pseudo table in your trigger to **know** what rows have been inserted ...... right now, you're always updating the **whole** table! (even if you insert only a handful of rows....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause is incorrect.  The correct comparison should be `0` rather than `1`:

```
WHERE d.quantity > 0 OR i.quantity > 0
```

Or alternatively, it should use `>=` assuming the quantities are integers:

```
WHERE d.quantity >= 1 OR i.quantity >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to subtract sum of all the quantity available in tblinvoice table from tblPurchase table's quantity. Instead you need to subtract only the currently inserted quantity. Please try with below code. Hope your problem will be resolved.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trig_invoice_update] 
ON [dbo].[tblInvoice]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE p
    SET quantity = COALESCE(d.quantity, 0) - COALESCE(i.quantity, 0) 
    FROM tblPurchase p 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT itemName, quantity
         FROM inserted i       ) i ON p.itemName = i.itemName 
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT d.itemName, SUM(d.quantity) AS quantity
         FROM tblPurchase d
         GROUP BY d.itemName) d ON p.itemName = d.itemName
    WHERE d.quantity > 1
       OR i.quantity > 1;
END
```